# Github enterprise login in Blueocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean, github-enterprise

I am not sure what happened but during the setup of a pipeline via blueocean(jenkins) I am unable to view my repos. It returns a **Error: fetch failed: 500** on the web console and when i do

1. `curl -v -H 'Authorization: token **********'  https://github.<my-enterprise>.com/api/v3` it returns 200,
2. `curl -v -H 'Authorization: token **********'  https://github.<my-enterprise>.com/api/v3/user` it returns 200 and
3. `curl -v -H 'Authorization: token **********'  https://github.<my-enterprise>.com/<my-username>` it returns 302.

It was working just fine a few days ago. I have even done a fresh install but it still wont go through. Any help will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
apparently github-api plugin has received an update to 1.110. For a temporary fix, Downgrading it back to 1.106 did the trick.

courtesy: [jenkins issue box](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61822?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20blueocean-plugin%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Blocker)